# which paypal webhook will i receive on next billing cycle payment in subscription

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-webhooks

i am getting webhook for new created subscription which are
`BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.CREATED` , `BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.ACTIVATED` AND `PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED`

i am giving access them premium feature on `BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.ACTIVATED` webhook.

if my subscription is monthly and i had buy subscription on 1st jan, so on my next billing time maybe 1st february , which webhooks i will receive on 1st february, how can i know paymenent is done on 1st feb

Answer (score 0):

PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED is the only important one, you can build all your business logic based on solely that webhook, updating your records every time you get it

BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.CREATED is of zero value, and BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.ACTIVATED is not necessary

If necessary to aid in reconciliation, you can add a `custom_id` parameter when creating the subscription. This will be returned in all future webhooks for that subscription.

Comment: on 1st feb next billing cycle will i get payment.sale.completed?

Comment: For subscription management, there are several important ones, especially BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.CANCELLED, BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.UPDATED

Comment: Not particularly important no, all logic can be based on PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED

Comment: It is a rare use case that needs to guess in advance whether the next cycle is going to complete. It's never a fact until PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED